React Native file doesn't make App.js file
I'm a newbie on using React Native. My problem is whenever I create a new react native file, App.js is not created.
And I try making new react native files, but App.js has not been found in my folder. How to fix this? Thank you.

read and understand this
https://react.dev/learn/importing-and-exporting-components

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
